# Query taking so much time in mysql but not in oracle

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Why following query takes so much time in mysql but not in oracle

```
select * from (select * from employee) as a limit 1000
```

I test this query in oracle and MySQL database with 50,00,000 records in this table.

I know that these query should be write like

```
select * from employee limit 1000
```

But for displaying data & total no of rows to our custom dynamic grid we have only one query we use simple `select * from employee` query and then add limit or other conditions.

we short this problem.

But my question is "Why such query in mysql takes too much time?"

Comment: Because the version of MySQL you use does not optimize the query by rewritting/removing the derived table. Try it with mysql 5.6 or MariaDB 5.5, too.

Comment: The first query will take almost exactly 0 seconds in Oracle because it won't run there - the syntax is invalid for Oracle.

Comment: yes you are right @a_horse_with_no_name i forgot to give alias

Comment: Oracle does not support the `limit` clause (unless you are on Oracle 12c)

Comment: @DarshanPatel What is your Oracle database version?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Oracle 11g

Comment: @DarshanPatel As mentioned above `limit` clause is not supported in Oracle before 12c version. So that query should give you an error. Are you sure that you run it on Oracle database, the version is not 12c and it completes successfully?

Comment: yes we use rownum in where condition 
but if query is 
select * from (select * from employee) as a where rownum <=1000

then also according to my thinking it first execute 
select * from employee 
then data comes in temporary memory 
and then other where clause is applied to filter these data
correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @DarshanPatel Do you have any `ORDER BY` in your actual query? If yes then try adding index on that columns.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin order by is not there

i think i should search on what happens internally when queries are execute in both database

thanks all for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

Well, because to perform this query MySQL has to go over all 50K rows in the table, copy them to a temp table (in memory or on disk, depending on size) and then take the first 1000.

In MySQL, if you want to optimize queries with `LIMIT`, you need to follow some practices that prevent scanning the full data set (mainly indexes on the column you sort by).

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: Ok @Galz but why this query execute fast in oracle?

Comment: Because the oracle optimizer is better than the mysql optimizer.